# How to simplify game loop with multiple classes

Tags: c++

For my current project I have several classes defining levels for the game. All of the levels are of the following form:

```
class Level1
{
public:
    Level1(int initialFrame);
    void update(int frameCount, sf::RenderWindow* renderWindow);
    void draw(sf::renderWindow* renderWindow);
    bool finished;
};
```

Note that none of the definitions for the functions update and draw are the same between levels.
In main my loop looks something like this:

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow renderWindow();

    frames = 0;
    progress = 0;

    Level1* level1 = new Level1(0);
    Level2* level2 = 0;
    Level3* level3 = 0;
    while (true) // Not actually like this, just put it here to illustrate my point
    {
        renderWindow.clear()

        if (progress == 0)
        {
            level1->update(frames, &renderWindow)
            level1->draw(&renderWindow)
            if (level1->finished)
            {
                delete level1;
                progress++;
                level2 = new level2(frames);
            }
        }

        if (progress == 1)
        {
            level2->update(frames, &renderWindow)
            level2->draw(&renderWindow)
            if (level2->finished)
            {
                delete level2;
                progress++;
                level3 = new level3(frames);
            }
        }

        if (progress == 2)
        {
            level3->update(frames, &renderWindow)
            level3->draw(&renderWindow)
            if (level3->finished)
            {
                delete level3;
                progress++;
            }
        }

        frames++;
        renderWindow.display();
    }
}
```

So I wanted to simplify this as I have the similar blocks of code running over and over. To solve this I created a template as such:

```
template <class T>
void loop(T level, int frameCount, sf::RenderWindow* renderWindow, int* progress)
{
    level->update(frameCount, renderWindow);
    level->draw(renderWindow);
    if (level->finished)
    {
        delete level;
        *progress++;
    }
}
```

This partly works, but I'm stuck on how to, a) Initialise the next level when one is finished in the template, and b) how to implement the template function in my game loop without using a check for progress, and manually programming in each level like I had before. Ideally I'd want something like a list of levels in the order I want them to be played, and progress could index which one I'm using the loop on, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: If they all have the same functions names which require the same parameters, you can use inheritance and polymorphism. Have a `vector` or similar which contains the `Level`s too. `for ( Level *level : levels ) { while ( !level->finished ) { … } }`

Comment: How about a "level done" function in the level class itself, which return a pointer to the next level object?

Comment: Don't assign `0` to pointers. Use `nullptr`. I'm a little surprised you're not getting a compiler warning for that.

Comment: Also, "template" has a very specific meaning in C++ that doesn't mean what you're using it for in your question. Not a big deal, but it might introduce confusion when discussing things like this. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking this.

Define a Level interface which is implemented by all your levels

```cpp
class Level {
public:
    virtual void update(int frameCount, sf::RenderWindow* renderWindow) = 0;
    virtual void draw(sf::renderWindow* renderWindow) = 0;
    virtual bool finished() = 0;
};
```

Then simply create a queue of levels and pop from it

```cpp
auto Levels = std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Level>>();
Levels.push(std::make_unique<Level1>());
Levels.push(std::make_unique<Level2>());
Levels.push(std::make_unique<Level3>());
std::unique_ptr<Level> currentLevel = Levels.front();
Levels.pop();
while(true){
  if(currentLevel->finished()){
    if(Levels.empty()){
       break;
    currentLevel = std::move(Levels.front())
    Levels.pop();
  }
  currentLevel->update(frames, &renderWindow)
  currentLevel->draw(&renderWindow);

  frames++;
  renderWindow->display();

}
```

If you absolutely need to pass in the frames at construction time, or you don't want to allocate the memory ahead of time, you could make a list of functionals instead, where the function returns a `std::unique_ptr<Level>`.

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing your code. Firstly, what do you mean by `currentLevel = Levels.pop()`, Doesn't pop() returns a type of void? Did you mean Levels.front()? When I tried that, I got the an error about std::default_delete<Level> being a deleted function that cannot be referenced. I'm guessing I have to create a destructor for Level and Level1, Level2, etc...? I've tried doing so, but that hasn't fixed it. Also, just to make sure `class  Level1 : public Level` is the correct way to implenent the Level class right? Thanks.

Comment: I think fixed the code now. You were completely correct - `pop()` returns void. `front()` then `pop()` seems to be the correct way to go.

Comment: Sorry I don't think my wording was clear, after I used `currentLevel = Levels.front()` that error occured. I believe it's because std::unique_ptr cannot be copied, but I've fixed it by ignoring the currentLevel variable and just using `Levels.front()` wherever I need it. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `=0` without `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a abstract base class of level:

```
class Level
{
public:
    Level(int initialFrame);
    virtual ~Level();

    virtual void update(int frameCount, sf::RenderWindow* renderWindow) = 0;
    virtual void draw(sf::renderWindow* renderWindow) = 0;

    bool finished;
};
```

and let all your levels inherit from this class:

```
class Level1 : public Level
{
public:
    Level1(int initialFrame);
    void update(int frameCount, sf::RenderWindow* renderWindow) override;
    void draw(sf::renderWindow* renderWindow) override;
};
```

And then just swap between them depending on the current progress.

```
Level* currentLevel = new Level1(0);
...
while (true)
{
    currentLevel->update(frames, &renderWindow)
    currentLevel->draw(&renderWindow)

    if (currentLevel->finished)
    {
        delete currentLevel;
        progress++;
        switch(progress)
        {
        case 1: currentLevel = new Level2(...); break;
        case 2: currentLevel = new Level3(...); break;
        case 3: currentLevel = new Level4(...); break;
        ...
    }
}
```

So you save yourself some `if`-blocks.

Comment: I'd add the `override` keyword to the child class definitions for clarity and some extra compile-time checking. Clear answer. :)

Comment: @3Dave Thanks, I never used this myself, but it seems pretty useful.

Comment: It's (in a very high level sense) similar to `const`. You don't really need it, but it keeps you from (accidentally) doing stupid things later on. Really, it's most useful in a team environment, or when someone inherits your code and tries to extend it without your advice. I have code in service, for a company I haven't worked for in close to a decade, that was written in '98. Every few years I get a call asking why something won't build.